# What is wrong with my plot_lab code in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

The function is as expected:

```
%% plot 3D plot with true color marker
plot_Lab(4,Lab,1,'',12,0);

plot_Lab(mode,Lab,createnewfig,markercolor,markersize,storeme)
% This function visualizes several different CIE-Lab_plot plots from 
% CIE-Lab coordinate data in 'Lab'.
```

I enter this:

```
plot_Lab(4,[45.9470,1.5130,5.2120],1,'',12,0);
```

and get the following error messages

```
Error using lab2xyz (line 25)
Incorrect number of columns in LAB data.

Error in applycform (line 88)
    out = c.c_func(columndata, cdata{:});

Error in applycformsequence (line 11)
    out = applycform(out, cforms{k});

Error in applycform (line 88)
    out = c.c_func(columndata, cdata{:});

Error in plot_Lab (line 68)
    RGB = applycform(Lab',cform);
```

Does anyone know where I got it wrong? Please help.

Comment: Without knowing the function I'd say you have not entered a correct form of the `lab` variable.

Answer (score 1):

`plot_Lab` is not a built-in function. Therefore you are supposed to provide its code or [link](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44965-plot-lab-color-coordinates/content/plot_Lab.m), so one could follow you.

According to the link,

> %          Lab         [3 x n]    -> Lab coordinates of n datapoints

`Lab` is supposed to be 3 x n. What you are provided is 1 x 3. So, you probably need to [transpose it](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html):

```
plot_Lab(4, [45.9470,1.5130,5.2120].', 1, '', 12, 0);
```

Comment: Yes erfan, I got it: plot_Lab(4,[45.9470;1.5130;5.2120],1,'',12,0);